# How to publish Qgis2threejs output online?

Tags: qgis, web-mapping, qgis2threejs

I want to have something like this: http://maps.navigasi.net/examples/stack_layer/soil_layer.html , my problem is because when i put the Html file outside of the original directory it does not run.

[image]

Comment: And if you copy the full folder and not just the html file?

Comment: Did you see this link? http://maps.navigasi.net/examples/stack_layer/soil_layer.html

Comment: Yes. I assume you want to point out that it links to one html file? Does this make you think that this one html file does not contain references to any additional files?

Comment: My point is: when i run the tool, it gives me 8 files including the .*html file, but imagine if i want to share this file with you. What i want is to send you the "link" of my file not the directory (folder).

Comment: Can you elaborate the question a bit more?

Comment: Well, i would like to have one link to share my results of Qgis2threejs tool. It´s because when i run the tool (Qgis2threejs) it gives me 8 files including the html file, as you can see in the pic. So what i want is something like -  http://maps.navigasi.net/examples/stack_layer/soil_layer.html .

Answer (score 2):

The html file is not intended to run on its own. In fact, html files almost never are. They usually reference images, css files, javascript files and other resources.

What is normally done is, that one puts them all onto a server. On this server they are exposed via http and a link to them can be shared.

Have a look at the network graph below. These are the resources which are loaded when your link from above is clicked.

[image]

As an alternative, if all local references in the file are relative you can also package the folder to a zip and send it to someone else.

Comment: "What is normally done is, that one puts them all onto a server". I saw that... in this case the server was maps.navigasi.net, do you know any server that i could use to have the same result?

Comment: They are relative, but i don´t want to put them in a zip.

Comment: Search the internet for "webhosting"